# How to get a specific item from a column of a table in MySQL and use it to make another <select> change its visibility

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

my problem is i want to get specific item from column of table here with photo [1]: https://i.ibb.co/4KcwScM/Captfffffure.png "the first item of the title" i want to get this specific value and hide and visible some option

here is the code to explain more , this select i want when people select this specific title it will show them another specific section which in this photo [2]: https://i.ibb.co/hyRcfPS/Carrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrpture.png ""the section will show" , and when they show other options it will hide the previous section and visible a new section to all the other options [3]: https://i.ibb.co/K05PpkL/Capturffffffffffae.png "this one explain every thing".

```
<label style="margin-left:20px; padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 39px;">كيف نساعدك؟  </label><select name="topic"  id="type" Required="Required">
        <option>اختر الخدمة</option>
<?php
// Make the connection:
$connection = mysqli_connect ('localhost', '#', '#', '#');
// If no connection could be made, trigger an error:
if ($connection->connect_error)
{
    die("Database selection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}
# Set encoding to match PHP script encoding.
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
$query = "SELECT * FROM newservices";
$select_newservice = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($select_newservice)) {
echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['title']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select><br>
```

this code after the first one

```
<div id="price"> 
<label style="    margin-left: 136px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;     padding: 0 20px;">سعر الخدمة</label><select disabled style="
    -webkit-appearance: none;
"    Required="Required">
        <option>0$</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="tax"> 
       <label style="margin-left:40px;     padding: 0 20px;"> سعر الخدمة شامل الضريبة</label><span class='prisee'>0$</span><br>
       </div>
```

here is the ajax of it

```
<script>
 $("select[name='topic']").on("change",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //getting selected  value
    var topic=$(this).val();
    console.log(topic);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contactusprise.php',
             data: {'topic': topic },//<-passing value to php
            success: function(php) {
               $("#price").html(php);//<--response will show in div with id=price
            }               
        });

    });
</script>
<script>
 $("select[name='topic']").on("change",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //getting selected  value
    var topic=$(this).val();
    console.log(topic);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contactustax.php',
             data: {'topic': topic },//<-passing value to php
            success: function(php) {
               $("#tax").html(php);//<--response will show in div with id=price
            }               
        });

    });
</script>
```

this is code it and the other are the same but with different row

```
 <?php
    // Make the connection:
    $connection = mysqli_connect ('localhost', '#', '#', '#');
    // If no connection could be made, trigger an error:
    if ($connection->connect_error)
    {
        die("Database selection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }
    $topic=$_POST['topic'];//<-getting value which is passed from ajax
    # Set encoding to match PHP script encoding.
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
 //here column name will be name of coulmn which you need to compare 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM newservices where id= ".$topic;
    $select_newservice = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    echo '<label style=" margin-left: 136px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;padding: 0 20px;">السعر بضريبة البيبال</label><select  style="
    -webkit-appearance: none;
" disabled name="topic1"   Required="Required">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_newservice)) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\" >".$row['tax']."</option>\n  ";
}

    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

code of this section of the specific item which from specific column i am already found solution of select the item and show it ,the problem it get the section for all items of select and i want to hide when the select isn't this item
the code for this section of the specific item

```
<div id="containeer" >
<div id="chango" style="
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 286px;
">
<label style="margin-left:20px; padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 39px;">عدد الصفحات </label> <input type="text" class="form-controle" name="topic1" placeholder="اختر العدد" style="
    width: 118px;
    text-align-last: center;
">
    </div>
<div id="wprice" style="display: inline-flex;
    width: 286px;" >
<label style="margin-left:20px; padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 39px;">عدد الكلمات</label><select style="-webkit-appearance: none;    width:118px;
    text-align-last: center;" Required="Required">

</select>
</div>
<div id="pricee" style="
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 286px;
"> 
<label style="    margin-left: 136px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;     padding: 0 20px;">السعر الاجمالي</label><select disabled style="
    -webkit-appearance: none;margin-right: -65px;
"    Required="Required">
        <option>0$</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="pricees" style="
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 286px;
"> 
<label style="    margin-left: 61px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;     padding: 0 13px;">السعر الاجمالي شامل الضريبة</label><select disabled style="
    -webkit-appearance: none;margin-right: -60px;
"    Required="Required">
        <option>0$</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the ajax codes

```
<script>
 $("input[name='topic1']").on("change",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //getting selected  value
    var topic1=$(this).val();
    console.log(topic1);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'wpcontactusnum.php',
             data: {'topic1': topic1 },//<-passing value to php
            success: function(php) {
               $("#wprice").html(php);//<--response will show in div with id=price
            }               
        });

    });
</script>
<script>
 $("input[name='topic1']").on("change",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //getting selected  value
    var topic1=$(this).val();
    console.log(topic1);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'price_pages.php',
             data: {'topic1': topic1 },//<-passing value to php
            success: function(php) {
               $("#pricee").html(php);//<--response will show in div with id=price
            }               
        });

    });
</script>
<script>
 $("input[name='topic1']").on("change",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //getting selected  value
    var topic1=$(this).val();
    console.log(topic1);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'taxprice_pages.php',
             data: {'topic1': topic1 },//<-passing value to php
            success: function(php) {
               $("#pricees").html(php);//<--response will show in div with id=price
            }               
        });

    });
</script>
```

there is the  wpcontactusnum.php code the other are same but different rows

```
<?php
    // Make the connection:
    $connection = mysqli_connect ('localhost', '#', '#', '#');
    // If no connection could be made, trigger an error:
    if ($connection->connect_error)
    {
        die("Database selection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }
    $topic1=$_POST['topic1'];//<-getting value which is passed from ajax
    # Set encoding to match PHP script encoding.
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
 //here column name will be name of coulmn which you need to compare 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM details where pages= ".$topic1;
    $select_detail = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    echo '<label style=" margin-left: 31px; 
    margin-bottom: 39px;padding: 0 20px;">عدد الكلمات</label><select  style="
    -webkit-appearance: none;width: 118px;
    text-align-last: center;
" disabled name="topic1"   Required="Required">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_detail)) {
        $detail_words = $row['words'];
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['pages']."\"  >".$row['words']."</option>\n  ";
}

    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I suspect that if you want help on SO, inclusion of things like '@mysql_fetch_assoc' is a really bad idea.

Comment: so what show i use?

Comment: @Swati can you help?

Comment: do you use ajax for that to show data ,whenever the select option changes ? if yes , post that as well also post code which you used to display your item.

Comment: @Swati add it above

Comment: why so many ajax call for same element ,also on select of first dropdown , you are getting another dropdown ,still didn't understand what you want to achieve , can you elaborate ?

Comment: topic1 for call the pages ,words,price,tax  and topic for the price which will dispear the other section look the third photo you will understand and i will update the code again

Comment: @Swati updated have a look

Comment: So on change of `topic` you are showing `price` and `tax` ,then on change of `topic1` you are showing other option ,now you need to hide the `topic1` select box if again `topic` dropdown is selected and load new values am i right?

Comment: @Swati  on change of topic if the item is the first option change topic1 to hide and when the change of topic if second item is selected hide the price and tax and show topic1

Comment: '@' in PHP code suppresses warnings. In development code, this is really unhelpful. At the top of the page, you're using PHP's insecure and deprecated mysql_ API; again, a really bad idea. Luckily (and somewhat mysteriously), things improve further down the page.

Comment: @Strawberry yeah hhhhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the selected option is first or second you can do like below :

Ajax code :

```
 $("select[name='topic']").on("change",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

  //checking if first option is selected
    if($(this)[0].selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        //hide topic1
        $("select[name='topic1']").hide();
         //show price and tax
         $("#price").show();
         $("#tax").show();
    }
   else if($(this)[0].selectedIndex == 1) {
      //hide price and tax
       $("#price").hide();
         $("#tax").hide();
      //show topic1
        $("select[name='topic1']").show();

   }
  });
```

Comment: so  `<div id="wprice" style="display: inline-flex;
    width: 286px;" >` i want to hide all the divs of price and tax and pages and words and price and tax when the page start and when they select it show

Comment: `<div id="wprice" style="display: inline-flex; width: 286px; visibility:hidden; overflow:hidden; position:absolute;" >`  i tried it with this style it didn't show and it took space in the page @swati

Comment: use `display:none;` and whenever you need to show that div do `$("yourdivid").show();` under jquery.